# JavaEE with IceFaces 3.1.0 - Components do not initialize correctly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xhtml, glassfish, icefaces

I'm currently working with IceFaces framework version 3.1.0 (ACE components).

Everything's doing fine, except one thing. When I run the application for the first time, the components seem to have troubles during initialization. They're all messed up, do not provide functionality (click events, filters) and lack of style.

What I don't understand is that all I have to do in order to make them work properly is to refresh the page, then all problems are gone. The components display correctly and work fine.

Have you got any similar troubles? I really don't know what could be the cause of all this.

The application consists of a xhtml template that encapsulates other xhtml files which actually are the various functionalities of the application. With each xhtml file (other than the template) comes the associated managed bean for programming logic.

I assume it's only the initialization phase that has troubles, since once I refresh everything works fine.

If any of you has an idea, please let me know!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your ace components space separated in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.icefaces.mandatoryResourceConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>dataTable panel chart menu menuItem menuBar dateTimeEntry textEntry dialog pushButton maskedEntry</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Damn, it was on the official migration guide. I'm ashamed I didn't see it before. Thanks a lot!